# fetch csv feed and place into database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

So from scratch, I have a CSV feed. Its currently 2596 lines long (Yay)

This feed gets updated frequently, I'm wanting to have this csv feed, (Baring in mind when i click the link it instantly downloads as a csv file.) to populate my database daily at a random time (e.g. 5am in the morning) every morning the database table would wipe and repopulate via the csv. (the way i access the csv is via url)

How would i go about this using rails? I'm unaware if there is any gems or anything i could use for this.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do it via rails - rails is a web framework, this is more a background task. If the population of the database needs to know your application structure, I'd set this up as a rake task in lib/tasks/populate.rake
Your question is much to broad to answer fully without more details, but generally something like the below should work.

Edit: delete users and recreate from an assumed structure

```
require 'open-uri'
namespace :populate do
   desc 'wipes the database and recreates from CSV'
   task reload: :environment do 
       # Remove all users
       User.delete_all
       CSV.new(open(YOUR_CSV_URL)).each do |row|
         # do something with the row
         User.create(name: row[0], address: row[1])
       end
   end
end
```

You could then use Cron or equivalent to call this at 5am
`cd /path/to/your/web/app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake populate:reload`

Comment: Ha opps i've put database, I'd really only need the table to be redone!

Comment: Youve also put something to do with the row? I'm not understanding 200% what this means? Would it be how it the database knows its on a new row? Could you give me a guide for dummies explanation? haha!

Comment: Hi there, I got an error on a ), Does the url need to be inside ""?

Comment: yes. I would assume that you'd assign it to a (static) variable rather than just sticking the URL in there but, yes it does need to be a string

Comment: You missed the : from populate, It should be :populate, However i now have an issue finding the table (guessing your example User is the table)

Comment: You've opened another question with my code, so I'll leave it there to be solved